# Should I use Ubuntu OS on a new laptop supplied without an OS?

Tags: system-installation, system

I am looking at purchasing a new laptop without an operating system from PCSPECIALISTS, but they will not advise me as to whether it will be OK to use UBUNTU OS. Can someone please advise if it is OK to use UBUNTU?

The laptop specification is:

- Chassis & Display: 15.6" Matte HD LED 16:9 Widescreen (1366x768)
- Processor (CPU): Intel® Pentium® Quad Core Processor N3520 (4 x 2.16GHz) 2MB Cache
- Memory (RAM): 4GB KINGSTON SODIMM DDR3 1600MHz (1 x 4GB)
- Graphics Card: Integrated Intel® HD Graphics
- Memory - Hard Disk: 500GB SERIAL ATA II 2.5" HARD DRIVE WITH 8MB CACHE (5,400rpm)
- DVD/BLU-RAY Drive: Ultra Slim 8x SATA DVD±R/RW/Dual Layer (+ 24x CD-RW)
- Memory Card Reader: Internal 9 in 1 Card Reader (MMC/RSMMC/SD: Mini, XC & HC/MS: Pro & Duo)
- Sound Card: Intel 2 Channel High Definition Audio + MIC/Headphone Jack
- Bluetooth & Wireless: GIGABIT LAN & WIRELESS INTEL® N-7260 (300Mbps, 802.11BGN) + BLUETOOTH
- USB Options: 3 x USB 2.0 PORTS + 1 x USB 3.0 PORT AS STANDARD
- Battery: Genesis Series 32WH Battery (Up to 9.5 Hour Battery Life)
- Operating System: NO OPERATING SYSTEM REQUIRED
- Keyboard Language: GENESIS SERIES INTEGRATED UK KEYBOARD
- Notebook Mouse: INTEGRATED 2 BUTTON TOUCHPAD MOUSE
- Webcam: INTEGRATED 1MP HD WEBCAM

Comment: visi https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since there aren't any dedicated graphics card, and you have 4 GB of RAM, and also you have 500 GB of hard disk space, so, you won't be able to play any high-end games.

Again, if you use softwares like Adobe Photoshop, Adobe Dreamweaver, AutoCAD, etc. then it is inevitable. You have to use Windows.

But if you can compromise on the above two factors, then, you can definitely use Ubuntu without any second thought.

But I would suggest that you first dual boot your laptop with windows and Ubuntu and see that how much time you spent on the two OSes. Then decide on the OS you want to keep.